# Program Variance and Standard Deviation Using Pointer Function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, variance

So i'm trying to make a standard deviation and variance function and I can't really figure out why it doesn't work. I'm suppose to call variance in case 3 and SD in case 4. everything else works in the program. If you see anything that doesn't look right let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Max_Nums 20

void sortNums(float nums[], int size);
float meanValue(float nums[],int size);
float medianValue(float nums[], int size);
void var_stdDev(float nums[],int size,float *var,float *stdDev);
float sqrtf(float);

int main (void)

{   

    int NumValue = 0;
    float array[Max_Nums];
    int i=0;
    int choice=0;
    float avg=0;
    float median=0;

    printf("How many numbers do you wish to enter (Max of 20): ");
    scanf("%d",&NumValue);

    while (NumValue<1 || NumValue>Max_Nums)
    {
        printf("Invalid response. You must enter a value between 1 and 20.\n");
        scanf("%d",&NumValue);
    }
    printf("Enter %d real numbers: ",NumValue);

    for (i=0;i<NumValue;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
    }

    do
    {
        sortNums(array,NumValue);
        printf("-----Menu-----\n\a");
        printf("Enter 1 for mean value\n");
        printf("Enter 2 for median value\n");
        printf("Enter 3 for variance\n");
        printf("Enter 4 for standard deviation\n");
        printf("Enter 5 to exit the program\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                avg=meanValue(array,NumValue);
                printf("The mean is:%.2f\n",avg);
                break;
            case 2:
                median=medianValue(array,NumValue);
                printf("The median is:%.2f\n",median);
                break;
            case 3:
                //printf("The variance is:%.2f",variance);
                //break;
            case 4:
                //printf("The standard deviation is:%.2f\n");
                //break;
            case 5:
                printf("Exiting the program\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nInvalid, try again");
                break;
        }
    }while (choice!=5);


return 0;
}

void sortNums(float nums[], int size)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    float z;

    for(x=0;x<(size-1);x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<size-x-1;y++)
        {
            if(nums[y]>nums[y+1])
            {
                z=nums[y];
                nums[y]=nums[y+1];
                nums[y+1]=z;
            }
        }
    }
}

float meanValue(float nums[],int size)
{
    int i;
    float avg;
    float sum;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sum+=nums[i];
    }
    avg = (sum/size);
    return avg;
}

float medianValue(float nums[], int size)
{
    float EvenMed;
    float Med;
    void sortNums(float nums[], int size);
    if (size%2==0)
    {
        EvenMed=(nums[size/2]+nums[size/2-1])/2;
        return EvenMed;
    }
    else
    {
        Med=nums[size/2];
        return Med;
    }

}

void var_stdDev(float nums[],int size,float *var,float *stdDev)
{
    int i;
    float sum;
    float meanValue(float nums[],int size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sum+=pow((nums[i]-meanValue,2);
    }
    *var=sum/(float)size;
    *stdDev=sqrt(*var);



}
```

Comment: please explain better the problem you are having

Comment: `sum` is uninitialized in 2 of your functions... Initialize `sum` to `0` in `meanValue()` and `var_stdDev()` functions.

Comment: @mik1904this is the error that pops up "In function 'var_stdDev':|error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'float' and 'float (*)(float *, int)')|||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|"

Comment: @CherubimAnand that doesn't change the error message

Comment: `meanValue` is a function. You need to call the function, not subtract the function from `nums[i]`.

Comment: Aside: you have function prototypes inside other function implementations, even though you have them at the top. In one case, in `medianValue`, that function is not even called. I suggest you read carefully through the program from top to bottom.

Comment: @WeatherVane I suspect he doesn't understand the difference between a function prototype and a call of the function. It looks like he expects that to sort the numbers.

Comment: @Barmar good point, I see your answer.

Comment: I haven't coded in a year and forgot most of my knowledge of C but what @Barmar wrote is correct and fixed my issue that I was having.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
    sum+=pow((nums[i]-meanValue,2);
```

This is trying to subtract a function pointer from a number, which makes no sense. You need to **call** the `meanValue` function to get the mean, and then subtract that.

Also, you didn't initialize `sum` before adding to it.

```
void var_stdDev(float nums[],int size,float *var,float *stdDev)
{
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float mean = meanValue(nums, size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sum+=pow((nums[i]-mean,2);
    }
    *var=sum/(float)size;
    *stdDev=sqrt(*var);
}
```

There's no need to have a declaration of `meanValue` inside `var_stdDev`, the declaration at the top of the file serves that purpose throughout.

In `medianValue()`, you have a declaration of `sortNums()`, but you never call it, so the numbers aren't sorted (it seems like you don't understand the difference between a prototype and a call).

```
float medianValue(float nums[], int size)
{
    float EvenMed;
    float Med;
    sortNums(nums, size);
    if (size%2==0)
    {
        EvenMed=(nums[size/2]+nums[size/2-1])/2;
        return EvenMed;
    }
    else
    {
        Med=nums[size/2];
        return Med;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well explained by [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002476/2410359) , OP's code has a number of problems:

```
void var_stdDev(float nums[],int size,float *var,float *stdDev) {
    int i;
    // sum not initialize
    float sum;  
    // unneeded function declaration
    float meanValue(float nums[],int size);

    // missing code to find the mean

    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        // improper call to accumulate the average derivation from the mean
        sum+=pow((nums[i]-meanValue,2);
    }
    ...
```

---

Recommend a new approach to standard deviation calculation

[image] from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods)

```
std = sqrt(n*sum_of_squares - sum_of_x*sum_of_x)/n
```

Suggested improvements:

Use `double` for intermediate calculation.  `float` is fine to reduce storage and sometimes for speed.  Yet statistics often subtract values leading to significant lost of precision. Use `double`.

Due to rounding, select data sets could result in a tiny negative number - even if mathematically the result should be >= 0.0.  So good to check sign before `sqrt()`.

Handle case when `size == 0` and do not perform a run-time division by `0`.

```
void var_stdDev2(const float x[], size_t size, float *var, float *stdDev) {
  double sumx = 0.0;
  double sumxx = 0.0;
  double std = 0.0; // Used when size == 0.0 - or set to NaN
  if (size > 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      sumx += x[i];
      sumxx += 1.0 * x[i] * x[i];
    }
    double std = sumxx * size - sumx * sumx;
    std = std >= 0.0 ? sqrt(std) : 0.0;
    std /= size;
  }
  if (stdDev) *stdDev = (float) std;
  if (var) *var = (float) sqrt(std);
}
```

Minor bits:

Use a `const` in the signature as function does not modify `nums[]`.

Array are best indexed with `size_t` rather than `int`.